# SQL Server Reporting: Generating reports by writing own code OR using any reporting server

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services

We have a mid size sql 2008r2 database with around (4 millions of row in a single table). we also have around 15 different reports which i guess 60% revolves round this table and its child. Users can generate reports for as low as 1 day or for 1 year also for all our reports user had to choose a certain date range.

Below is the schema for that table (dummy)

```
Table Txn
-------------------------------------------------------------
  ID |  StartDate |   EndDate |  FK1 |  FK2 | FK3 |  Amount1 | Amount 2
```

and off course there are other table as well but for sake of simplicity i would leave that.

Currently we are not using any external tool/server to generate reports and are managing report generation by our self and rendering in static HTML page.

We are noticing that for querying 4 million rows and filtering around 10% or data is taking 75 seconds, i had looked into queries and it is pulling consolidated data only so improving query might help much here.

My question does the tools like SSRC or others only help in rendering part? do they also contribute in optimizing the way data can be fetched?

Answer (score 0):

AJAX-enabled data grids are very good at pulling in large amounts of data.  This [tool](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/DataBinding/LargeDatabase.aspx) from DevExpress retrieves 300,000 rows in less than a second.  I've found that filtering works in a matter of 1-2 seconds.

SSRS pagination will also help as the page will render more quickly.  Use a Filter (not a query parameter) and you should should have good performance filtering once the initial dataset is retrieved.

And of course you want to add indexes to the main table.  Run a trace and save the trace to a file, then use the file in Database Engine Tuning Advisor.  That will help define which indexes you need.